# Didn't Gordon expect the consequences of the ridiculous comedy show?

Tags: plot-explanation, v-for-vendetta

Gordon Deitrich works in the British news network. He makes a ridiculous show on Chancellor Adam Sutler in a Television show. When Evey asks what will he do, he gives non-serious answers.

> Gordon(In phone) - What are they gonna do, fine us?
>   Big deal. We've got the most-watched show on air.
>   Well, you're my agent,
>
> Evey - Is everything a joke to you?
>
> Gordon - Only the things that matter.
>
> Evey - What if they come after you?
>
> Gordon - I tell you what's gonna happen. I'll have to make some kind of apology, do some boring fundraiser. In the meantime, our ratings will go through the roof. It'll be fine. Trust me.

He looks so assured about his future but we know that he's aware of the character of Adam sutler by the portraits and Gordon's collection.

Why did he make this show even though he knew about the character of Adam Sutler?  Didn't he expect that consequences would be dangerous after the show? On a side, note He also had collection like the Quran which Sutler hated the most.

Answer (score 6):

> Why did he make this show even though he knew about the character of Adam Sutler? Didn't he expect that consequences would be dangerous after the show?

Clearly he didn't...that seems obvious from the dialogue.

He's supremely confident that due to the popularity of the show and his standing any consequences would be relatively minor.

What got him killed was the contents of his hidden room behind his wine cabinet.

V actually says...

> I thought they'd arrest him......but when they found a Koran in his house, they had him executed.

Comment: While I do think that you're exactly right (he was executed because of his secret room), Gordon's assumption was indeed wrong. The officers who entered his home were immediately violent with him (before discovering the secret room); while Gordon was merely expecting an administrative punishment.

Answer (score -1):

Within *V for Vendetta*, Gordon is an analogue for 'freedom of speech', or more specifically freedom of the press.

Side note: most people don't realize that freedom of the press is a uniquely American concept; we don't actually have in the UK, where *V for Vendetta* is set. In this country, Super-injuctions and D-Notices serve as 'press gags', wherein a court can legally force the press not to report on something. They can't even report that they can't report on it.

Dietrich's believes (and by extension, as a rational man, the citizens also believe) that their liberties and freedoms are somehow enshrined.

What Sutler demonstrates is that a power of authority is able to manipulate the press without abandoning the 'principles', and as such without *technically* doing anything wrong. Dietrich is not 'bagged' for his speaking out against Sutler. He is 'bagged' under obscenity laws for his sexuality. The Koran found on his premises seals his fate.

Regardless of which 'Law' Sutler enacts, the aims and results are the same/ The 'free press', i.e Dietrich, has been silenced. Constitutionally speaking, Gordon's 'freedom of speech' castle was armor plated. The problem with attacking those in power, however, is that they often possess the keys to the back door.